# Adding EDIT button in Sales Order in NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I'm new to NetSuite and I need to add the blue "Edit" button in the sales order form. I tried to add a button via Workflow but it doesn't show up.

In case I need to use SuiteScript, how do I enter the script file to manually code the edit button? See the screenshot for reference.

[image: Edit button screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

The edit button is  based on the permission of transaction for each role